# Progress bar on click in another page

Tags: wordpress, elementor

for one of my website I would like that when a user clicks on a button in a page, a progress bar advances in another page.
This is to allow users to follow their progress.
I can do it in JS but in the same page, I don't know how to transfer the data to another page.
I have searched with many plugins but I can't find anything.

If someone has had this problem, I'm interested in a solution.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can do this with JavaScript, the only thing you need is a way to store the progress information locally on the visitors browser, maybe in some sort of a `local storage`.

See here on how this can be done (using local storage): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

**Store Info:**

```
localStorage.setItem('myProgress', 1);
```

**Retrieve Info on any page:**

```
const myProgress = localStorage.getItem('myProgress');
```